# CSS rules selectors (e.g. $('ul li{color:red;width:50px} span')

Tags: jquery, css

Consider following:

```
<style>
   #foo{color:red}
</style>
<div>
    <div id='foo'>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div style="color: red">C</div>
</div>
```

How to fetch all DIVs that have some specific css rules (e.g. their color are red)? Is there any plugin to extend jQuery selectors to accept css rules (e.g. `$('ul li{color:red;width:50px} span')`?

Comment: you can use the [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector but be aware of the other conditions like if parent is hidden then it will select the child and height:0 conditions that goes along with it

Comment: I don't think there's a "good" way to do this. All the methods that I can think of (that cover ALL cases) include iterating through EVERY element, and checking to see whether it's computed style is of the value you are looking for.

Comment: asking for a lot of work due to complexities of rgb vs hex vs textual colors in style sheets and different browsers handle color differently. I would look for a libsrary that already has what you want in it. you can't do it with jQuery selectors....you have to parse the style property of elements

Answer (score 1):

As per your question

**`How to fetch all DIVs that have some specific css rules (e.g. their color are red)?`**

```
$.each($('*'), function () {
    if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        alert($(this).text());
     }
 });

This will get all elements with color Red
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpGER/3/)

**Addition**

As **`*`** will be selecting all the elements in Dom, we can narrow down our search by specifying the type of elements we are looking for. for example here we have `div` elements only so we can use

```
$.each($('div'), function () {
    if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        alert($(this).text());
     }
 });
```

Comment: But the `*` selector! So slow! I don't think there's a way to avoid it though.

Comment: yes @uber5001, we can narrow down selection elements if we know the types, for example here are divs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").find("div:hidden")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("div[style*=display:block]")
```

Comment: Isn't `style` the attribute, not `display`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style="display: none"]')
```

but that would require that your `style` attributes are consistently formatted...

If you are looking to get *all* elements that have a certain css property (not just in the `style=` attribute), you may have to do it manually, by looking through the [document stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets).

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to depend upon [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) because it selects

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

So try

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).doSomething()
```